# Error "Conversion to non-scalar type requested"

Tags: c, multithreading, select, server, threadpool

I'm trying to implement a multithread server with a thread pool and using the select, so I have `fd_set set` declared globally that I pass to the function that the thread pool runs.I get this error

> In function ‘threadF’ conversion to non-scalar type requested
>         fd_set set1=(fd_set) s;

and the code is this

```
pool *createPool(int size){
    /*...*/
    if((err=pthread_create(&id,NULL,&threadF,(void *)&set))!=0){
        fprintf(stderr,"thread\n");
        exit(errno);
    }
    /*...*/
}

void *threadF(void* s){
    fd_set set1=(fd_set) s;
    /*...*/
}
```

Maybe I'm forgetting something?

Comment: @Lundin it's usually a struct.

Comment: this is the select http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html I have not declared any fd_set struct but used the already predefined one

Comment: You'd have to declare `set` somewhere though. Anyway, I'm pretty sure the reason is as described in the posted answer.

Comment: show the type declarations.

Comment: simply `fd_set set, rdset;` declared as a global variable

Comment: @james No, that's a bad idea. Especially if this structure is part of a larger array that should be parallelized by a thread pool. Passing it as parameter to pthread_create like you do is much better design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Scalar types* is the formal name for arithmetic types (regular variables) and pointers. The opposite is *aggregate types*, which is arrays and structs. The compiler thinks you are making a conversion from scalar `s` to something else. In plain English: don't convert from a pointer to a struct instance.

The scalar `s` is a pointer, but you cast this to a struct type, rather than to a pointer to a struct (which is what you pass to pthread_create). Try:

```
fd_set* set1 = (fd_set*)s;
```